# AngularJs FTP multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to upload multiple files using angular js  but the values are not getting stored in the model filestore

Htmlcode:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-repeat="file in filelist">
          <label>{{file.name}} </label> 
          <input type="file" ng-model="filestore[$index]" />
   </div>  
</div>

<div>
     <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="savefiles(filestore)"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
 myApp.controller('uploadCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

 //list of file names
 $scope.filelist = ["file1", "file2", "file3"];

 //save file list
 $scope.savefilelist = function(filestore) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/SaveFiles',
        data: filestore
    });
 };
```

})

Comment: Angular doesn't support ng-model on file elements

Comment: Is filestore a standard js object array?

Comment: yes filestore is a standard js object aaray to contain the files

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/7b0G59z0ExglBane87um?p=preview

Here is the example how you could do it by custom directive.

```
app.directive("fileBind", function() {
  return function( scope, elm, attrs ) {
    elm.bind("change", function( evt ) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope[ attrs.fileBind ] = evt.target.files;
      });
    });
  };
});
```

If you need to use `ng-repeat`, here is the alternate solution.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aJAmbo?p=preview

1. use object if using binding within ng-repeat loop.
2. use binding in the directive so that complex reference can be easily realized.

Comment: i tried it... but the ng-repeat is not printing all the files.. its taking only the last file...

Comment: also i want to have multiple files to be uploaded... updated your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DF2WYU

Comment: There is two ways to select multiple files, `multiple` attribute in input element (my plunker) or multiple input elems (your way).  It  depends on which you prefer.

Comment: The multiple input elements(my way), i am not able to get it working. Can you please update the plunker above.